# How can I optimize my line movement in Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, methods

[Running Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbxCx.png)

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import math

class Template:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("2D Display")

        self.canvas = self.canvas_display()
        self.line1 = self.line_creation(500 * .3,0,500 * .3, 1000)
        self.line3 = self.line_movement_creation(0, 0,2000, 0)

        self.speedx = 0 # Movement of Line3
        self.speedy = 9 # Movement of line3
        self.active = True
```

```
        #self.move_active()  #Code that creates the problem
```

It makes a grid currently. As soon as I try to make the horizontal lines move. The program crashes. Works without `self.move_active()` so I commented it out.

```
        self.canvas.update()

    def canvas_display(self):  #canvas
        canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=500, height=400, 
    background='black')
        canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        canvas.update()
        return canvas


    def line_creation(self,x,y,x1,y1): #creation of multpie lines
        spacing = 0
        for i in range(11):
            self.canvas.create_line(x + spacing, y ,x1 + spacing ,y1 , 
                                           width=2, fill="white")
            spacing += 100
    
    def line_movement_creation(self,x,y,x1,y1):
        spacing1 = 0
        for i in range(11):
            self.canvas.create_line(x, y+spacing1 ,x1 ,y1 + spacing1 
                                           ,width=2, fill="white")
            spacing1 += 100
```

These two functions line_creation and line_movement_creation create horizontal and vertical lines. Both are working well.

```
    def line_update(self): #line movement method
        self.canvas.move(self.line3, self.speedx, self.speedy)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.line3)
        if pos[3] >= 800:                #o
            self.canvas.move(self.line3, self.speedx,self.speedy-800)

    def move_active(self):
        if self.active:
            self.line_update()
            self.window.after(40, self.move_active)

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
```

These two functions make the lines move. I think the problem is making the 10 lines and trying to move them all at once, or just these functions itself but I have no idea.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Temp = Template()
        Temp.run()
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is here. Why can't you do the same thing for the horizontal lines as for the vertical lines, but changing the lines' `x` coordinate instead of their `y` coordinate?

Comment: I did, it created a grid like pattern. I then tried to make the lines move but I was meet with an error. I will update the code.

Comment: For everyone that see this when I try to run the program with the commented  #self.move_active() I get:                                                                                     tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!canvas move tagOrId xAmount yAmount"

Comment: This error is because `line3` is `None` when you pass it to `self.move_active()`. It is `None` because it is set to the return value of `self.line_movement_creation()`, which doesn't return anything. I will see what I can do, but it may take a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```py
import time
from tkinter import *

class Template:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("2D Display")

        self.canvas = self.canvas_display()
        self.line1 = self.line_creation(500 * .3,0,500 * .3, 1000)
        self.line3 = self.line_movement_creation(0, 0,2000, 0)

        self.speedx = 0 # x movement of line3
        self.speedy = 9 # y movement of line3
        self.active = True

        self.move_active()  #Code that creates the problem
        self.canvas.update()

    def canvas_display(self):  #canvas
        canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=500, height=400, background='black')
        canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        canvas.update()
        return canvas

    def line_creation(self,x,y,x1,y1): #creation of multple lines
        spacing = 0
        lines = []
        for i in range(11):
            id = self.canvas.create_line(
                x + spacing,
                y,
                x1 + spacing,
                y1, 
                width=2,
                fill="white",
            )
            lines.append(id)
            spacing += 100
        return lines

    def line_movement_creation(self,x,y,x1,y1):
        spacing1 = 0
        lines = []
        for i in range(11):
            id = self.canvas.create_line(
                x,
                y+spacing1,
                x1,
                y1 + spacing1,
                width=2,
                fill="white"
            )
            lines.append(id)
            spacing1 += 100
        return lines

    def line_update(self): #line movement method
        for line in self.line3:
            self.canvas.move(line, self.speedx, self.speedy)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(line)
            if pos[3] >= 800:
                self.canvas.move(line, self.speedx, self.speedy - 800)

    def move_active(self):
        if self.active:
            self.line_update()
            self.window.after(40, self.move_active)

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Temp = Template()
    Temp.run()
```

The difference: I made `line_creation()` and `line_movement_creation()` each return a list of the IDs of the lines that they created. `line_creation()`'s list is saved to `self.line1`, and `line_movement_creation()`'s list is saved to `self.line3`. `line_update()` then uses `self.line3` to move the horizontal lines.

Here is the old `line_update()` method:

```py
def line_update(self): #line movement method
    self.canvas.move(self.line3, self.speedx, self.speedy)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.line3)
    if pos[3] >= 800:                #o
        self.canvas.move(self.line3, self.speedx,self.speedy-800)
```

...and here is the new `line_update()` method:

```py
def line_update(self): #line movement method
    for line in self.line3:
        self.canvas.move(line, self.speedx, self.speedy)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(line)
        if pos[3] >= 800:
            self.canvas.move(line, self.speedx, self.speedy - 800)
```

As you can see, the only difference here is that it iterates through all the lines in `self.line3` and moves each one individually. The movement coordinates are exactly the same.